# Get height of html with static width in Go

Tags: html, go, height

I am using https://github.com/slotix/pageres-go-wrapper to get images of html files in my application. In order to do this, I need the height and the width of the image I want to create. I plan on using a static width so that's no problem. My issue is that I do not want to use a static height. I want to create an image that is exactly the height of the html's document.body.scrollheight so as to neither crop out the bottom of the page or to leave empty white space at the bottom of the image. My question is, is there any way to get the document.body.scrollheight value or any eqivalent value from an html document before the html document is loaded, provided I know the width the document would load with? In other words, given an html file and a static width, can the height of a that html page be derived?

Comment: Not without rendering it completely, no.

Comment: And if I were to render it completely, do you know how I might get the height of the page using go?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you use to render it. Most headless browser libraries provide a method of DOM inspection you can use to get the rendered page dimensions.